# How to determine why a patch request in a test is unsuccessful

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, integration-testing

In a test I have a `patch request`. However, it doesn't save. I know this because after the `patch request` I test whether the new values are there.

How can I discern why the `patch request` in the test fails?

The patch request:

```
fullname = "MyName"
phone = "MyPhone"
patch member_path(@user), member: { phone: phone,
                                   fullname: fullname,
                                   password: "",
                                   password_confirmation: "" }
puts @response.message
puts @response.status
assert flash[:success]
assert_redirected_to @user
@user.reload
assert_equal @user.fullname, fullname
Etc.
```

I have looked at `test.log` but also from there I don't see why the patch request doesn't save the new values.

Test.log:

```
Started PATCH "/members/980190962" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-05-01 21:26:59 +0000
Processing by MembersController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"member"=>{"phone"=>"MyPhone", "fullname"=>"MyName", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "id"=>"980190962"}
...
  [1m[35m (0.1ms)[0m  SAVEPOINT active_record_1
  [1m[36mMember Exists (0.2ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  1 AS one FROM "members" WHERE (LOWER("members"."email") = LOWER('orgone@example.com') AND "members"."id" != 980190962) LIMIT 1[0m
  [1m[35mMember Exists (0.2ms)[0m  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "members" WHERE (LOWER("members"."username") = LOWER('myst1') AND "members"."id" != 980190962) LIMIT 1
  [1m[36m (0.1ms)[0m  [1mROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT active_record_1[0m
  Rendered shared/_error_messages.html.erb (1.7ms)
...
```

Also I added `@response.status` and `@response.message` to the test after the patch line. But these don't generate any additional output so that I still don't understand why the `patch request` isn't succesful (it does work in development).

The update method in the controller:

```
  def update
    @member = Member.find(params[:id])
    if @member.update_attributes(memberupdate_params)
      flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
      redirect_to @member
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

private
def memberupdate_params
  if ((current_member && current_member.admin?)
    params.require(:member).permit( :email,
                                    :username,
                                    :fullname,
                                    :phone,
                                    :admin,
                                    :password,
                                    :password_confirmation)
  else
    params.require(:member).permit( :email,
                                    :username,
                                    :fullname,
                                    :phone,
                                    :password,
                                    :password_confirmation)
  end
end
```

Comment: I think you just need to reload the user before testing the fullname.  `@user.reload`.  It may be getting updated, but you still have an outdated copy of it loaded in your test.

Comment: Sorry, I only posted a few lines. In the actual test I reload, so that's not it. I've added these lines to my original post.

Comment: Check the content of `log/test.log` file.

Comment: Thanks, I can't understand from the test.log what the cause of the error is. I've added it to my original post.

Comment: From the log it's obvious that the `Member` record you're trying to create already exists.

Comment: But I'm not trying to create a new record, I'm trying to update an existing one. Is that perhaps where something is going wrong?

Comment: Please update your question with the code for your update action.

Comment: I added the update method from the controller (it works in development, so the problem seems to be with the test).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test log SQL looks wrong here:

```
"members"."id" != 980190962
```

I would expect the opposite:

```
"members"."id" = 980190962
```

Are you positive that your development environment and test environment are using the same gem versions, same Rails version, etc.?

Broadly, a Rails `update` will be wrapped in a transaction. A common cause of failure is a validation error. See the `validate!` method for how to validate, and also look at the model class to see if you're requiring any special validations.

You may want to try a simple code change, temporarily, to see if Rails raises an exception.

Change this area:

```
if @member.update_attributes(memberupdate_params)
  ...
```

To this bang method:

```
@member.update_attributes!(memberupdate_params)
```

Comment: That's smart, by temporarily changing it with the "bang method" there is an explicit error message in the terminal that allowed me to find out what was going on. It turned out that the username of a user in the fixtures did not pass validation (1 character short in size).